# Installed Coldfusion 10 PDFs stop displaying

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, iis-7.5, coldfusion-10

Just like the title says. Not sure what could cause this. We had CF9 installed, Windows Server 2008, IIS7.5. We uninstalled CF9 and installed CF10.

The CF applications work fine, but now, PDFs don't display on certain browsers (IE, Firefox, Chrome all latest versions). Just get a blank page. What could have caused something like this? I've checked that application/pdf mime type is listed in IIS. Truly stumped here.....

Comment: When you say that are not displaying do you mean a) the files exist and are downloaded, but the result is a blank page b) the files exist but are not served, c) the files are no longer being created d) or something else?

Comment: The files exist on the server, but nothing happens. Just a blank page.

Comment: Try this - run the page again and when you get the blank page, resize your browser. Does that make it appear? I've been seeing that lately (not CF specific, but any PDF) and believe it's a problem in the Acrobat plugin